# AngularJS, Link function in directive, how to update attrs when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying out some stuff. Sometimes successfully, sometimes not.
Here is what I am (unsuccessfully) trying to do:
The user clicks a button, and a random score for a football game is calculated. Depending on whether our team wins or loses, the displayed message changes. This works.
What doesn't work though is that I want my css class to change as well.
I am trying to do that through a link function in the directive (because I am learning the link and compile functions at the moment), but it seems that the attrs are loaded once at the start of the app, and an not be modified.
OK, maybe I should share my code:

1/ The interesting part in my index.html

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ScoreController as score">
        <h4> {{ score.test }} </h4>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="score.scoreCalculation();">Check the score</button>
        <div display-result class="grey" result="{{ score.result }}">
           <h4> {{ score.message }} </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2/ My very simple css file

```
.grey {
    border: solid grey 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.win {
    border: solid green 5px;
}

.lose {
    border: solid red 5px;
}

.draw {
    border: solid orange 5px;
}
```

3/ My controller

```
function ScoreController () {
    // ctrl = this;
    this.message = "The game is about to start!";
    this.scoreFrance = 0;
    this.scoreArgentine = 0;
    this.test = "France - Argentine";
    // this.result = "";
    this.color = "";
    this.scoreCalculation = () => {
        let France = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        let Argentine = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

        if (France > Argentine) {
            this.message = `France Wins! ${France} - ${Argentine}`;
            this.result = "win";
        } else if (France < Argentine) {
            this.message = `France Loses! ${France} - ${Argentine};`
            this.result = "lose";
        } else {
            this.message = `It's a draw! ${France} - ${Argentine}`;
            this.result = "draw";
        };
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ScoreController', ScoreController);
```

4/ My directive

```
function displayResult () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.addClass($attrs.result);
        }
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('displayResult', displayResult);
```

Now, I was hoping that thanks to the `result="{{ score.result }}"` that I am passing to my directive via the `attrs`, the css class for my message would be updated. But no, the  `attrs.result` stay at the value they were initially when I console.log them.

Let me know if you know a way around, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link` runs one time for each directive when it initializes, here you want to update class after that, for attrs it is done with observe:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('result', (value) => {
        $element.addClass(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved it!
I had this before the ```add.Class``` line though:
```$element.removeClass("rwin")
$element.removeClass("lose")
$element.removeClass("draw")
```

Otherwise it kept on adding these classes to the html, and gets confused at one point, not knowing which colour to display.
Thanks a lot!